# Are the continuous functions on $G$ dense in $L^{1}(G)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

If $G$ is a locally compact group, is the set $C_{c}(G)$ of all continuous functions on $G$ with compact support dense in $L^{1}(G)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A more general result is the following:

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$. Then for any $p \in (0, \infty)$, $C_c(X)$ is a dense subset of $L^p(X, \mu)$.

See Proposition 3 in [Terry Tao's blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/245b-notes-12-continuous-functions-on-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces/) for a proof (this post also appears as a chapter in Tao's book *An Epsilon of Room*). Another reference is Proposition 7.9 in Folland's *Real Analysis*.